# Pytorch reconstruction loss

Tags: pytorch

If i have two tensors

```
truth = [N, 1, 224, 224]

net_output = [N, 1, 224, 224]
```

and I want to minimize the net_output to match the truth, is this the correct way to apply the loss?

```
mse = nn.L1Loss().cuda()
FPL = mse(truth, net_output.detach())
```

`N` is the batch size. Will my l1 loss be summed over the `N` images?

Comment: yes. BTW, "mse" stands for **m**ean **s**quare **e**rror which is L2 loss and not L1.

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum over N you have to [set the reduction to sum](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.L1Loss)

```
l1 = nn.L1Loss(reduction='sum')
loss = l1(net_output, truth)
```